# Categorical models for truncations of the sphere spectrum

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, monoidal-categories

Picard $n$-groupoids are expected to model stable homotopy $n$-types. So far this has been proved for $n=1$ in

> Niles Johnson, Angélica M. Osorno, *Modeling stable one-types*. Theory Appl. Categ. 26 (2012), No. 20, 520–537; [arXiv:1201.2686](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2686).

and for $n=2$ in

> Nick Gurski, Niles Johnson, Angélica M. Osorno, *The $2$-dimensional stable homotopy hypothesis*. Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra, Volume 223, Issue 10, 2019, Pages 4348-4383. [arXiv:1712.07218](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07218).

In particular, for $n=1$, Johnson and Osorno have also shown that the free Picard groupoid on one object $\mathbb{S}$ models the $1$-truncation of the sphere spectrum. In detail, this is the Picard groupoid where

- The objects of $\mathbb{S}$ are the integers;
- For $m,n\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathbb{S})$, we have
  $$
  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{S}}(m,n)
  \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}
  \begin{cases}
      \emptyset         &\text{if $m\neq n$,}\\
      \mathbb{Z}_{2}    &\text{if $m=n$;}
  \end{cases}
  $$
- The monoidal structure $\oplus$ on $\mathbb{S}$ is given by addition of integers;
- The symmetry of $\mathbb{S}$ at $(A,B)$ is the morphism $\beta^{\mathbb{S},\oplus}_{m,n}\colon m\oplus n\to n\oplus m$ defined by
  $$
  \beta^{\mathbb{S},\oplus}_{m,n}
  \overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}
  \begin{cases}
      0             &\text{if $mn$ is even,}\\
      \eta_{m+n}    &\text{if $mn$ is odd,}
  \end{cases}
  $$
  where $\eta_{m+n}$ is the unique non-zero element of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{S}}(n,n)$.

In section 3 of the same paper, they also show that there is a symmetric monoidal functor
$$\xi\colon\mathbb{F}\longrightarrow\mathbb{S}$$
from the symmetric monoidal category of finite sets and bijections $\mathbb{F}$, the categorification of the monoid of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$, defined on objects by the inclusion $\mathbb{N}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ and on morphisms by the sign map $\mathrm{sgn}\colon\Sigma_{n}\to\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

**Questions.** Here are some questions around these topics:

- Free Picard $n$-groupoids on one-object are supposed to model the $n$-truncations of the sphere spectrum. Is there some sense in which free symmetric monoidal $n$-categories on one object model the $n$-truncations of the "directed sphere spectrum"?
- The zeroth and first truncations of the sphere spectrum are given respectively by the abelian group of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ and by the Picard groupoid $\mathbb{S}$ above. What are the second and third truncations of the sphere spectrum, or, equivalently, how can we explicit describe the free Picard $2$- and $3$-groupoids on one object?
- The free symmetric monoidal $n$-categories on one object for $n=0,1,2$ are given by the commutative monoid $\mathbb{N}$ of natural numbers, the symmetric monoidal category $\mathbb{F}$, and the discrete monoidal bicategory on $\mathbb{F}$ (see [arXiv:1210.1174](https://arxiv.org/abs/1210.1174), Corollary 1.11). What is an explicit description of the free symmetric monoidal tricategory on one object?

Comment: Related: [link 1](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/12/spans_in_2categories_a_monoida.html#c040400), [link 2](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2011/12/spans_in_2categories_a_monoida.html#c040463).

Comment: Regarding your first question, what's the "directed sphere spectrum"?  Unless this concept has been otherwise defined, you're free to *define* it as the free symmetric monoidal n-category on one object.  However, I believe this will be vastly less interesting than the free symmetric monoidal n-groupoid on one object: inverses are what make things complicated here.

Comment: "What is an explicit description of the free symmetric monoidal tricategory?"  You mean free on one object.  I expect, but will not venture to prove, that this will be (equivalent to) the discrete monoidal tricategory on what you're calling $\mathbb{F}$.   And I expect that this boring pattern continues for higher $n$-categories.

Comment: [A preprint from last year](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.05577) proves the stable homotopy hypothesis for all n!

Comment: @JohnBaez Thanks! While there's no current definition of the "directed sphere spectrum", I think two notions we could compare the free symmetric monoidal $n$-categories on one object to are: 1) the (stable?) homotopy monoids of directed spheres and 2) the free symmetric monoidal $(\infty,\infty)$-category on one object. (I've asked about each of these [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/398259) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/398278))

Comment: @JohnBaez By the way, is there some natural explanation for why requiring inverses to exist make things more complicated, as you noted?

Comment: @ArunDebray That's a fantastic result! Thanks for pointing to it!

Comment: @Emily - if you work out an easy example like the free braided monoidal groupoid on one object $x$, you'll see how $\pi_3(S^2) = \mathbb{Z}$ arises from the braiding $B_{x,x}: x \otimes x \to x \otimes x$ together with the isomorphism $i: 1 \to x \otimes x$ and its inverse $e: x \otimes x \to 1$.

Comment: @JohnBaez Is it correct to say that the free braided monoidal groupoid on one object is the category $\mathbb{B}'$ where 1) we have $\mathrm{Obj}(\mathbb{B}')=\mathbb{Z}$; 2) For each $n,m\in\mathrm{Obj}(\mathbb{B}')$, the Hom set $\mathrm{Hom}(n,m)$ is empty if $n\neq m$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ otherwise; and 3) where the braiding $\beta\colon n\oplus m\to m\oplus n$ is given by the element corresponding to $nm$ in $\mathrm{Hom}(n+m,n+m)\cong\mathbb{Z}$? (By the way, sorry for the delay to reply!)

Comment: @Emily - what you've described sounds like the free braided 2-group on one object.  A braided 2-group is a braided monoidal groupoid where every object $x$ has an "inverse", meaning an object $y$ such that $x \otimes y \cong y \otimes x \cong I$, where $I$ is the unit for the tensor product.  The free braided monoidal groupoid on one object has objects $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(n,m)$ being empty if $n \ne m$ and the braid group $B_n$ if $n = m$.

Comment: @DavidRoberts - the "braided version of John's conjecture" discussed by Johnson and Yau concerns the free braided bimonoidal category on no objects, where a "bimonoidal category" is like a ring, or more precisely a rig: it has two monoidal structures, one distributing over the other.  In the conversation *here*, nobody has been talking about bimonoidal categories, as far as I can see.

Comment: @JohnBaez ah, my mistake, I forgot it was **bi**monoidal, I didn't go back in and double check.

Comment: @JohnBaez Oh, I see it now! I had misunderstood "free braided monoidal groupoid" as "free braided monoidal Picard groupoid", partly because of not realising the braid category is a groupoid (‍♀️). Thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnBaez $\newcommand{\B}{\mathbb{B}}$Can I ask one more question? I'm still a bit confused on how to relate $\mathrm{Hom}_{\B}(x\otimes x,x\otimes x)$ back to $\pi_3(S^2)$. From what I understand, we first start from $S^2$ viewed as the $\infty$-groupoid with a single object $\bullet$, a single arrow $1_{\bullet}$, and freely generated by a $2$-arrow $1_{\bullet}\Rightarrow1_{\bullet}$. Then we truncate that $\infty$-groupoid into a trigroupoid $\tau_{\leq3}S^2$ and deloop it twice, arriving at the free braided monoidal category on one object $\mathbb{B}$.

Comment: $\newcommand{\B}{\mathbb{B}}$It's at this point that I'm confused: why is it wrong to say that
$$\pi_3(\tau_{\leq3}S^2)\cong\pi_1(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{B}(\tau_{\leq3}S^3))\cong\pi_1(\mathbb{B})\cong\coprod_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathrm{B}_{n},$$
and instead we have $\pi_3(S^2)\color{red}{\cong}\mathrm{Hom}_{\B}(x\otimes x,x\otimes x)\cong\mathrm{B}_2\cong\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: When you take $S^2$ viewed as an $\infty$-groupoid in the manner you describe, and truncate it to a trigroupoid, and deloop it twice, you get the free braided "groupal groupoid" on one object, not the free braided *monoidal category* on one object.   A "groupal groupoid", more commonly called a 2-group, is a monoidal category where all objects and morphisms are invertible.   The objects of the free braided monoidal category on one object (namely $\mathbb{B}$) are not invertible!  Those objects - more precisely isomorphism classes of those objects - form the monoid $\mathbb{N}$.  So it's wrong.

Comment: @JohnBaez Oh great! So, writing $\mathbb{B}'$ for the free braided 2-group (do you know a good notation for it?), we have
$$\pi_0(\mathbb{B}')\cong\mathrm{Obj}(\mathbb{B}')/{\sim}\cong\mathbb{Z}\cong\pi_{2}(S^{2}),$$
and
$$\pi_1(\mathbb{B}';\mathrm{id}_{1})\cong\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathbb{B}'}(1)\cong\mathbb{Z}\cong\pi_{3}(S^{2}),$$
right?

Comment: That's right.   The fun part is seeing how, and why, the free braided monoidal category on one generating object collapses down to precisely this 2-group when we formally adjoin an inverse to the generating object.   (I don't know a wonderful name for this 2-group; maybe $B^2(\Pi_3(S^2))$ where $\Pi_3$ means "fundamental trigroupoid".)

Comment: @JohnBaez I have to disagree: this has been very fun since the start! Thank you so much, John! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand what you mean about the "directed sphere" so will focus on the other questions.

The free Picard $n$-category on one object has a description as a bordism $n$-category. Specifically it has:

- Objects are stably framed 0-manifolds;
- 1-Morphisms are stably framed 1-dimensional bordisms;
- 2-morphisms are stably framed 2-dimensional bordism between bordisms;

etc

until level $n$ where we take equivalence classes of stably framed $n$-dimensional bordisms between bordisms between ... and the equivalence relation is up to one more layer of stable bordism.

Using the Pontyragin-Thom construction, one can see that this is just the same as the fundamental $n$-groupoid of $\Omega^\infty S^\infty$.

The free (non-Picard) symmetric monoidal $n$-category is always just $\mathbb{F}$ when $n\geq 1$. This is explained in my answer to you other recent question. https://mathoverflow.net/a/398384/184